# Получить дерево папок через Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Приветствую. Помогите пожалуйста составить отношения в моделях.

Есть 2 таблицы:

Users

- user_id

Folders

- folder_id
- parent_id
- user_id

Требуется рекурсивно вывести дерево папок конкретного пользователя. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропишите в моделях пользователей :

```
public function folder()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Folders', 'user_id');
}
```

каталогов :

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Users', 'user_id');
}
```

Ну и далее при обращении, к примеру

```
User::find(1)->folder;
```

вы получаете список его каталогов, полученный результат уже выводите как Вам будет угодно.